Present continuois repeatable things with when
1 When he drives I'm scared
2 When he is driving I'm scared
Both versions are fine. 2 just uses present continuous even thought it's something repeatable not necessarily something happening at the moment to emphasize duration. My question is : can we get rid of when and put for instannce as long as or once in 1 and 2. Are then both versions still correct and stay with the same meaning?

I'm not sure what you mean by "even thought it's something repeatable not necessarily something happening at the moment to emphasize duration".  When he is driving does mean that he is driving at the moment you are talking about.

@ Kate Bunting. My teacher told me that 2 means either at the moment or it has the same meaning as 1 even though we use present continuous which is meant to emphasize duration that always during his driving I feel scared

You don't agree?

I couldn't understand your convoluted sentence. (1) means  'On every occasion that he drives, I am scared.' (2) means 'While he is driving I am scared".

So what is the meaning of 2? It's also always his drving?

I've just told you what (2) means!

But 2 means alaways or now at the moment?

@ Kate Bunting becauaw once you said it  referes to something current and then you wrote while he is driving that't why I'm confused

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Credit to you @KateBunting for your patience.

First, a practical suggestion. Based on the question, and reinforced by your later comments, I assume that you are a non native English speaker. So my advice is to simplify your learning and focus on one or two principles at a time. Learn them well before going on to other parts of the language.
For example, you begin with sentences that show two different tense structures: When he drives...; and When he is driving.... But then you go on to ask questions about conjunctions such as when, as long as, and once.
So, regarding the tenses, I would say that the present and present continuous mean essentially the same thing. Consider these sentences:

He drives the car.

He is driving the car.


There will be times when these sentences are slightly different, but often they will be two ways of saying the same thing. Certainly in your examples I see no difference worth commenting on:

He drives the car, and during that time I am scared.

He is driving the car, and during that time I am scared.


I've written it that way because that's what when means: "during the time that".
So putting aside the tenses, your actual question is about the use of different conjunctions. Can they be switched? And again I would encourage you to keep it simple. The general answer is that if two words mean the same thing you can exchange them; and over time you should work on learning the differences of detail that apply to different words.
These sentences all mean approximately the same thing:

When he drives I feel scared.

As long as he drives I feel scared.

Once he drives I feel scared.

During the time that he drives, I feel scared.


The main variation in these examples is once. That tends to point to the start of an activity. So the focus there is more on the point at which he begins driving. A native English speaker might say "Once he gets behind the steering wheel I feel scared." So at heart you can learn alternate words that basically mean the same, then study the details as you get more confident.

Continuous current action  pastgeneral action. That's what I know. Even though in my 2 example I want to show something general I use present continuous because my teacher told me that's fine and natives do it even if it something repeatable and simple seems to be the best

Now I want to know if it works the same way if I  use differeny conjunctions then when

@ Peter Kirkpatrick

@Adam, having read the chat thread that Kate set up, I assume that you now have the answers you want. But feel free to ask further questions if necessary.

That's it thanks
